# How do i add a number to another class formula to get answer?

Tags: java

```
public class maathclass {

    public void someNumbers() {
        int z = 4;

        System.out.println(z);

    }

}

//Trying to take variable z to add with answer from maathclass.java

import java.util.Scanner;

public class input {

public static void main (String args[]) {

        double fnum, snum, answer;
        Scanner userInput= new Scanner(System.in);
        maathclass mathObject = new maathclass();
        mathObject.someNumbers();


        System.out.println("Enter first number:");
        fnum = userInput.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter second number:");
        snum = userInput.nextDouble();

// i want to add the variable z to the answer

        answer = fnum + snum;
        System.out.println("Answer:" + answer);
    }

}
```

Comment: Start reading about the basics of programming

Comment: so you cant add a number from another class?

Comment: Yes, you can, but you are asking a simple programming question that isn't even language specific. Your question is telling us you have no clue how to code at all, and you need to get the basics out of the way. We are not here to write your code for you.

Comment: ou need to declare and set a member variable in your maathclass class and then reference it. Have a read here for some guidance: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do this

**maathclass.java**

```
public class maathclass {
        private int z = 4

        public void setZ(int z) {
           this.z = z;
        }
        public int getZ(){
           return z;
        }
}
```

**input.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class input {

public static void main (String args[]) {

        double fnum, snum, answer;
        Scanner userInput= new Scanner(System.in);
        maathclass mathObject = new maathclass();

        mathObject.setZ(4);


        System.out.println("Enter first number:");
        fnum = userInput.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter second number:");
        snum = userInput.nextDouble();

// i want to add the variable z to the answer

        answer = fnum + snum + maathclass.getZ();
        System.out.println("Answer:" + answer);
    }

}
```

or else if you desire to set the value of `z` from `maathclass` then just initialize it with the value in `maathclass` constructor.

Hopes this helps.